# How to match for an empty string in a grep pattern search?

Tags: awk, sed, grep, file-search

I have a set of files containing boot variables from several cisco switches in the network. I have an requirement to filter only the switches with the boot variable empty on the next reload and print the hostname

```
given this data
```

```
hostname1#show boot
---------------------------
Switch 1
---------------------------
Current Boot Variables:
BOOT variable = flash:cat9k_iosxe.bin;

Boot Variables on next reload:
BOOT variable = 
Manual Boot = no
Enable Break = no
Boot Mode = DEVICE
iPXE Timeout = 0

hostname2#show boot
---------------------------
Switch 1
---------------------------
Current Boot Variables:
BOOT variable = flash:cat9k_iosxe.bin;

Boot Variables on next reload:
BOOT variable = flash:cat9k_iosxe.bin;
Manual Boot = no
Enable Break = no
Boot Mode = DEVICE
iPXE Timeout = 0
```

```
desired result
```

```
hostname1
BOOT variable =
```

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the answers .. still trying to get them work... Couple of catches..1. we cant play around with the keyword 'hostname' they are just examples.. they may be just random, meaning one can have jax-sw-1 and another can have lhr-sw-1 ... 2. There is a space after the equal sign in  Boot variable =   .. i am sorry if this changes anything in the answer.. will accept the answer(or the closest one) once i figure out.. if you have more inputs please share in here! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk '{a[++i]=$0}/BOOT variable =.$/{for(x=NR-10;x<=NR;x++)print a[x]}' filename|awk '/^hostname/||/BOOT variable =.$/{print $0}'| sed "s/#.*//g"
```

Results in:

```
hostname1
BOOT variable =
```

Comment: ```
awk '{a[++i]=$0}/BOOT variable = .$/{for(x=NR-10;x<=NR;x++)print a[x]}' results_* |awk '/#/||/BOOT variable = .$/{print $0}'| sed "s/#.*//g"
```
with some slight edits i was able to get this work.. thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You could do something like

```
awk -F'#' '
  $2 == "show boot" {hostname = $1} 
  /BOOT variable =[ \t]*$/ {print hostname; print}
' file
```

Comment: or `awk -F '#| *= *' '$2 == "show boot" {host = $1} NF > 1 && $2 == "" {print host; print}'` -- requires gawk I think for the complex FS.

Answer (score 0):

Using grep and pipes:

```
grep -B8 -E '= $' file |grep -E 'hostname|= $'
```

The first grep extracts the line where there's nothing after '=' symbol and 8 lines before the match to extract the line with hostname.
The second grep filters the lines with **hostname** and **BOOT variable =**